# Conditional Join with replace and case

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, case

I have two tables that I want to join.

The case is in table 1 the default value is 1 then in table 2 the default value is 0

```
Table 1       Table 2
--------     ---------
1            0
1232342      1232342
1241232      1231231
```

I want to join table 1 and table 2 with condition that if table 2 is 0 then it will be replaced to 1.

```
SELECT T1.ID 
FROM TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2
WHERE T1.ID = REPLACE(CASE WHEN T2  = 0 THEN 1 ELSE T2.ID END, 'X', 'E')
```

with this statement it does not return the other id's that are not 0 or 1

expected output

```
Table 1      
--------     
1           
1232342
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What do you hope to achieve with the `replace()`? Clearly it will have no effect on the sample data you've posted, so what is your intent?

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions in WHERE and ON clauses.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a join with a CASE. `replace()` is for string values:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t1.id = case when t2.id = 0 then 1 else t2.id end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using case when :

```
SELECT * 
    FROM TABLE1 T1 inner join TABLE2 T2
    on T1.ID = (CASE WHEN T2.ID =0 THEN 1 ELSE T2.ID END)
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when and sub-query

```
select t1.* from table1 t1 join    
(
select case when t2.id=0 then 1 else t2.id end as id  from table2 t2
) as t3 on t1.id=t3.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Skip the `case` expression, simply use `AND`/`OR` instead:

```
SELECT T1.ID 
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE2 T2
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID OR (T1.ID = 1 and T2.ID = 0)
```

Or use `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE1
INTERSECT
SELECT case when ID = 0 then 1 else id end from TABLE2
```